# streaming from large files and creating an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, highland.js

I'm having problems with highland.js. I need to create an array of functions from my stream data, but can't get it to work. Here's my code, however `requests` is always empty.

```
var requests = [];           
_(fs.createReadStream("small.txt", { encoding: 'utf8' }))
        .splitBy('-----BEGIN-----\n')
        .splitBy('\n-----END-----\n')
        .filter(chunk => chunk !== '')
        .each(function (x) {

            requests.push(function (next) {
                Helpers.Authenticate()
                    .then(function (response1) {
                        return Helpers.Retrieve();
                    })
                    .then(function (response2) {
                        return Helpers.Retrieve();
                    })
                    .then(function () {
                        next();
                    });
            });

        });
        console.log(requests)
        async.series(requests);
```

Comment: I just re-read your question. Mind telling us what `async.series(requests)` does? But in general, if you're expecting to `console.log` the requests as seen on the line above `async.series` then of course it's going to return empty cause streams don't block just like async.

Comment: This is async.js (https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.series) library

Comment: I see. So it's unrelated to the issue you're facing. You probably need to create a promise or pass a callback for the stream to finish populating `requests` and then `console.log` out or perform `async.series` on it.

Comment: .each is a jQuery function. if you are using forEach, the X argument is not used.

Comment: @manuerumx it's a function in `highlandjs` too.

Comment: Maybe im wrong.  Helpers.Authenticate is an ASYNC function. EACH is a Sync method. So, you need to push inside the Authenticate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read [highland's](http://highlandjs.org/#done) doc. Try adding `.done` to your stream and `console.log` out the `requests`.

```
_(fs.createReadStream("small.txt", { encoding: 'utf8' }))
    .splitBy('-----BEGIN-----\n')
    .splitBy('\n-----END-----\n')
    .filter(chunk => chunk !== '')
    .each(function (x) {

        requests.push(function (next) {
            Helpers.Authenticate()
                .then(function (response1) {
                    return Helpers.Retrieve();
                })
                .then(function (response2) {
                    return Helpers.Retrieve();
                })
                .then(function () {
                    next();
                });
        });

    }).done(function(){
      console.log(requests);
    });
```

Comment: Wow - thank you. Worked like a charm. I was tearing my hair out trying to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the stream events to wire things up:

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream('small.txt', {encoding: "utf8"});

stream.on('data', (line) => {
    var lineStr = line.toString(); //Buffer to String
    /* You code here */
})

stream.on('close', (line) => {
    console.log(request);
})
```